# Galera Cluster Connection refused and gcs_group_handle_join_msg (): 736: Will never receive state. Need to abort

Tags: mariadb, replication, database-replication, galera

I'm doing an example with `Galera` cluster using 3 virtual machines with `Debian 9` and `MariaDB 10.1` database.

The replica works well using `rsync` method, even if a node is dropped when it recovers, it synchronizes normally. The problem arose when I turned off two nodes to see what happened. Inserting data in the node that remained and it worked fine but when I have started the other nodes it throws the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can not connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111 "Connection refused")
```

And the log of one of the nodes that I try to raise appears:

```
[ERROR] WSREP: gcs / src / gcs_group.cpp: gcs_group_handle_join_msg (): 736: Will never receive state. Need to abort.
```

I have no idea what could happen. I need help to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use sockets to talk between VMs.  Only use TCP/IP.